# Differentiate $f(x) = \frac{\sec \ x}{1 + \tan \ x}$

Tags: calculus

I don't understand line 3.

After using the Quotient Rule, how do I use the Trig identities to simplify the third line?

Also, what is the strategy when using trig identities, when do you know you are finished?

If I can choose between $\cot \ x = \frac{\cos \ x}{\sin \ x}$,  which one would I choose? $\cot \ x$,  or $\frac{\cos \ x}{\sin \ x}$?

Differentiate $f(x) = \dfrac{\sec x}{1+\tan x}.\;$For what values of $x$ does the graph of $f$ have a horizontal tangent?

---

**Solution**  The Quotient Rule gives $$\begin{align} f'(x) & = \frac{(1+\tan x)\frac d{dx}(\sec x) - \sec x \frac d{dx}(1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2}\\ \\
& = \frac{(1+\tan x)\sec x \tan x - \sec x \cdot \sec^2 x}{(1+\tan x)^2}\\\\
&= \frac{\sec x(\tan x + \tan^2 x - \sec^2 x)}{(1+\tan s)^2}\\ \\
&= \frac{\sec x(\tan x - 1)}{(1 + \tan x)^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: They just factor out a $\sec x$ from the terms on top.

Comment: You're finished with calc part of the problem by the end of line $2$.

Comment: Mnifldz when you said they factored out the secant. You can remove a secant from a sum of products? What law of real numbers is this?

Comment: To you point about simplification - the last expression is equal to $\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}$, which some would argue is more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer one of your querry:

Factor out $sec\ x$ and multiply $(1+tan\ x)tan\ x$ in the numerator of line 2. We now have the third line. Using the identity $tan^2+1=sec^2x$ we have line 4.

Comment: So you are always aiming for the identity to be very simple, as in one identity. For example cot x, instead of cos x / sin x?

Comment: I would say yes for simplicity. Also based from my experience if the original function involves say sec and tan, the answer is always in terms of sec and tan OR sec or tan. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess this is more of an Algebra question; however, line #2, when factoring out the sec x from the second terms, how should I view it? Since this is the inverse of the distributive property a(b+c)=ab+ac. Yet, I don't see that with this question.

Comment: Again based on my experience, most of the time, factoring out a common factor helps a lot in differentiation :-).

Comment: How did this answer either of the OP's questions?  The OP asked about simplifying Line 3, not arriving at it from Line 2.  And the OP wanted some guidelines as to knowing when to "stop" simplifying.

Comment: @Dr.MV I think that my point is that by using the identity included in the answer we can simplify line 3 to go to line 4, that simplifies line 3

Comment: @JrAntalan That's fair. But it didn't address the second question - "When do you know you are finished?"  That one is tougher since there is no objective answer.

Comment: I agree with you, an upvote for that :-).

Comment: @JrAntalan Thanks!!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dr.MV you are welcome Sir

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:  Third Line Issue
$\tan ^2x - \sec ^2 x = \left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)^2=\frac{\sin ^2x-1}{\cos ^2x}=\frac{-\cos ^2x}{\cos ^2x}=-1$

Question 2: General Question
It is a matter of choice really.  Inasmuch as you are talking  about equivalent expressions, then these expression are equally valid.  That said, one often chooses the form that is more "concise," whatever "concise" means to you.

So, in the case you mentioned, $\cot x$ versus $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, which seems more concise to you?  Moreover, the final expression is equivalent to $\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2}$.  Does that appear more elegant than Line 4 of the post?

Comment: tan x would seem more concise

Comment: That sounds very reasonable to me! I do understand your question and hope that I've helped some.

Comment: To you point about simplification - the last expression is equal to $\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}$, which some would argue is more elegant.